# pgfplots: How to move the legend in a multi-axis figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

This figure seems to always generate the legend in the top right, north east position. How would I move it to the south east? Passing the legend style to the plots themselves didn't seem to work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \pgfplotsset{
      scale only axis,
  }

  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line*=left,
    xlabel=Steps,
    ylabel= BLEU,
  ]
    \addplot[mark=*, color=blue]
      coordinates{
        (1, 0.00012801506090909243)(2372, 0.07797393202781677)(4726, 0.4955924153327942)
      }; \label{plot_1_y1}

    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[
      axis y line*=right,
      axis x line=none,
      ylabel= CHRF,
    ]

    \addplot[mark=x, color=red]
      coordinates{
        (1, 0.06872139871120453)(2372, 0.04961954057216644)(4726, 0.060143500566482544)(7070, 0.0851062685251236)

      }; \label{plot_1_y2}
    
    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_1_y1}\addlegendentry{$y_1$}
    \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=plot_1_y2}\addlegendentry{$y2$}
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE1 See package documentation, section *4.9.5 Legend Appearance*, page 259 - 267. Its position you can set by `axis` option `legend pos = ...`, for example `legend pos=south west,`.

Comment: This didn't seem to help in my case, I had to add something like 
  `\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append style={at={(0.9,0.1)},anchor=south east}}`

Comment: Oh, my suggestion works, however  it seems that I didn't select position which you like to have. I only intent to show you a way how you can positioned a legend. Anyway, you solve your problem yourself!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP solve his problem himself.